# python global variable scope confusion. What are these variables not accessible?

Tags: python, global-scope

I see there are a few of these questions on here, but I haven't found one that quit matches what I'm after.

I have a common file, lets call it tools.py. In this file I have a host of path definitions to use and an init_paths function to set some key paths based on command line arguments:

```
def init_paths(args):
    global tools_dir, tools_src, tools_bin

    if args.tools_set:
        tools_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(args.tools_set,"tools"))
    else:
        tools_dir = os.path.join(BAR_PATH, "tools")

FOO_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), ".."))
BAR_PATH = os.path.join(FOO_PATH, "foobar")
tools_dir = none
tools_src = none
tools_bin = none
```

etc...

I have a main file, lets call it main.py where I want to use these.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parseArgs()
    from tools import init_paths
    init_paths(args)
    doStuffFunction(args.one, args.two, args.three)
```

I have left out the meat and potatoes to be sure, but I believe this should be enough to illustrate my global scope problem.  when I run this: `python main.py --tools-set=/path/to/tools`, I am expecting the call to init_paths, to set up some key paths I wish to use later in the `doStuffFunction()`.

```
def doStuffFunction():
    searchPath = os.path.join(tools_dir, "folder")
```

this fails: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute endswith

pretty sure this is because it is not getting set. but why?

**EDIT**

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import argparse
import glob
from tools import *


def parseArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="parse my args")
    parser.add_argument("--toolchain-root", type=str,default=None,help='specify toolchain directory')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


def doStuffFunction():
    output = 'output'
    if not os.path.isdir(output):
        os.makedirs(output)
    gimmySugar(output)

def gimmySugar(output):
    fileList = []
    linkBook= {}

    searchPath = os.path.join(tools_BIN_ROOT,'gcc-4.8.5')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchPath):
        for libFile in glob.glob(root+'/*.so*'):
            fileList.append(libFile)
            if os.path.islink(libFile):
                linksWith = os.readlink(libFile)
                linkBook[libFile] = linksWith

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # script was called directly from the command line
    args = parseArgs()
    from tools import init_settings
    init_settings(args)
    doStuffFunction()
```

tools.py

```
import os

def init_settings(args):
    global tools_DIR, tools_SRC_ROOT, tools_OBJ_ROOT, tools_BIN_ROOT
    if args.toolchain_root:
        tools_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(args.toolchain_root, "toolchain"))
    else:
        tools_DIR = os.path.join(USER_DIR, "")
    tools_SRC_ROOT = os.path.join(tools_DIR, "src")
    tools_OBJ_ROOT = os.path.join(tools_DIR, "obj")
    tools_BIN_ROOT = os.path.join(tools_DIR, "bin")


ROOT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), ".."))
OUTPUT_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "outputs")
BUILD_PATH = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, "build")
USER_DIR = "/usr/lib64/"
tools_DIR = None
tools_SRC_ROOT = None
tools_OBJ_ROOT = None
tools_BIN_ROOT = None
```

Comment: `none` is not valid python, it's `None`. It's no use analyzing code that doesn't 100% reflect what you're doing.

Comment: "Global" variables are really module-level in Python. `tools.init_paths` is setting globals in the `tools` module, not the module that imports it.

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'm thinking that user2357112 might have answered my question, but I'm not sure yet on a solution. I will reduce my code to a small workable and EDIT this. hold on for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#This line will failed
searchPath = os.path.join(tools_BIN_ROOT,'gcc-4.8.5')
```

The scope of global variables is module level, `tools_BIN_ROOT` will not be shared without passing across modules.

The variable `tools_BIN_ROOT` is global variable ONLY in **tools.py**. Insteadly, **main.py** do not contain any global variable in **tools.py**.

For inspecting this, you can use `print(globals())` in both files.

---

> Do not use global variable if possible.

This is a simple workaround.

(*I strongly recommend you to refactor your code by config or OOP*)

**tools.py**

```
def get_tools_BIN_ROOT():
    return tools_BIN_ROOT
```

**os.py**

```
from tools import get_tools_BIN_ROOT
searchPath = os.path.join(get_tools_BIN_ROOT(),'gcc-4.8.5')
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution! I understand better now that global is module-level only; thanks again.